# Javascript how to iterate an array with iteration step 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, filter, reduce

Writing code in C/C++ way when we had to iterate an array we wrote

```
for(int index = 0; index < array.size(); index++) {
     doSomething(index);
}
```

when it was necessary to iterate by 4 we wrote

```
for(int index = 0; index < array.size(); index = index + 4) {
     doSomething(1, index);
     doSomething(2, index+1);
     doSomething(3, index+2);
     doSomething(4, index+3);
}
```

How can I achieve this by using JavaScript's map reduce or filter array functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Why you want to do that with `map`, `reduce` or `filter`? is there any logical reason for not using a regular for loop or an iterator? None of the three prototypes was built to be used for that purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a normal loop in JavaScript:

```
for(let index = 0; index < array.length; index += 4) {
     doSomething(1, index);
     doSomething(2, index + 1);
     doSomething(3, index + 2);
     doSomething(4, index + 3);
}
```

Also with `forEach` and modulus:

```
array.forEach((e, i) => {
  if (!(i % 4)) return;
  doSomething(1, i);
  doSomething(2, i + 1);
  doSomething(3, i + 2);
  doSomething(4, i + 3);
});
```

Comment: "Also with forEach and modulus" ... no, that makes little sense here.

Comment: I know @JonasWilms - the OP wanted a method-based solution too, so this was my approach. The first one is my preferred method however.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this with `map` or `filter` or other array functions, cause they do something for *every* element of the array.

But you can achieve this with the same syntax that you use in `c/c++` with a `for loop`:

```
for(let index = 0; index < array.length; index += 4) {
     console.log(index);
}
```